# Bug script não entrega os pontos da compra

Tags: php

Olá pessoal bom eu uso modern acc estou usando um sistema de compra e venda ele retira os pontos do banco de dados da conta e guarda em uma tabela no mesmo assim representando uma oferta em leilão porém caso eu compre direto sem dar o lance na hora de fazer a troca de personagem pelos pontos não acontece isso só retira os pontos de quem gastou ele ganha o personagem porém quem vendeu não recebe os pontos pela venda e da um erro.

o sistema é uma página em php vou estar postando aqui

como o código é muito grande eu coloquei neste site para não ficar gigante

https://hastebin.com/ajegobosaf.xml

Print do erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro diz que a chave `buy_know` não está definida para ser acessada em alguma variável. Mais especificamente nesta variável: `$auctionInfo['buy_know'])`. Você provavelmente queria digitar `$auctionInfo['buy_now'])`

O erro encontra-se nesta linha:

```
   $finishedAuctionOwner->setPremiumPoints($finishedAuctionOwner->getPremiumPoints() + $auctionInfo['buy_know']);
```

Comment: Creio que é isso também! +1

Comment: muito obrigado andrei e coelho me ajudaram muito foi isso mesmo o problema uma letra errada desculpa tomar o tempo de vocês

Comment: @Brunds tranquilo. Isso acontece mesmo.